# Удаление каталогов на сервере php

Tags: php

При загрузки аватаров создается каталог, в который загружается фотка, при загрузки нового аватара старый каталог из содержимым должен удалятся

```
if(isset($_FILES['profilepic'])){
    if((($_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/png") || ($_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/gif")) && ($_FILES["profilepic"]["size"] < 1048576))
    {
        $chars="abcdefgijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGIJKLMNOPRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        $rand_dir_name=substr(str_shuffle($chars),0, 15);
        mkdir("userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name");
        if (file_exists("userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name/".$_FILES["profilepic"]["name"]))
        {
            echo $_FILES["profilepic"]["name"]. "already exists";
        }
        else
        {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["profilepic"]["tmp_name"], "userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name/".$_FILES["profilepic"]["name"]);
//echo "uploaded and stored in userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name/" .$_FILES["profilepic"]["name"];
            $profile_pic_name=$_FILES["profilepic"]["name"];
            $profile_pic_query=mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `profile_pic`='$rand_dir_name/$profile_pic_name' WHERE `username`='$user'");
            function rmdirr($dirname)
            {
                if (!file_exists($dirname)) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (is_file($dirname)) {
                    return unlink($dirname);
                }
                $dir = dir($dirname);
                while (false !== $entry = $dir->read()) {
                    if ($entry == '.' || $entry == '..') {
                        continue;
                    }
                rmdirr("$dirname/$entry");
                }
                $dir->close();
                return rmdir($dirname);
            } 
            $deldir = "userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name";
            rmdirr($deldir);
            header("Location: account_settings.php");
        }
     }
```

Comment: Во-первых, стоило бы назвать проблему, с которой вы столкнулись.  
Во-вторых, выделить проблемный участок кода и привести его в порядок. И уже потом ждать совета.

Comment: function rmdirr($dirname) удаляет сразу же загруженную папку, а должна удалять старую папку с фоткой если такая есть

Comment: ну значит дело в путях, в виндоусе / а в линуксе \

дело в винде, код правильный

Comment: не в путях дело, а в от что оно удаляет ту папку которая  загрузилась, а нужно что бы удаляло прежднюю папку

Answer (score 2):

А что будет если `rand_dir_name` совпадут у разных пользователей?

Тут по любому нужно использовать структуру катологов по `id` пользователя.
Ну а сам аватар можно называть рандомно.

Стоит так же не забывать что в одном каталоге не может быть больше 15000 файлов или папок.

Исходя из всех этих условий я написал очень простой но многофункциональный класс загрузок

```
<?php
class functions {

    public function __construct() {

    }

    public static function arr_union(array $def_arr,array $new_arr) {
        foreach($new_arr as $key => $value) {
            if(array_key_exists($key, $def_arr) && is_array($value)) {
                $def_arr[$key]=self::arr_union($def_arr[$key], $new_arr[$key]);
            }
            else {
                $def_arr[$key]=$value;
            }
        }
        return $def_arr;
    }

    public function __destruct() {

    }

}
?>

<?php
class upload {

    public $id;
    private $upload_dir;
    private $max_file_count;

    public function __construct(array $param=array()) {
        $def_param=array('upload_dir'=>dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/uploads/','max_file_count'=>15000);
        $cache_param=functions::arr_union($def_param,$param);
        $this->upload_dir=$cache_param['upload_dir'];
        $this->max_file_count=$cache_param['max_file_count'];
        $this->del_id();
    }

    public function set_id($id) {
        $this->id=$id;
    }

    public function del_id() {
        $this->id=0;
    }

    public function find_upload($url) {
        if(is_file($url)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function get_upload($id,$fl) {
        $this->set_id($id);
        $dir_file_num=ceil($this->id/$this->max_file_count);
        $upl_file=$this->upload_dir.$dir_file_num.'/'.$this->id.$fl;
        $upl_file = str_replace(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)), '', $upl_file);
        return $upl_file;
    }

    public function put_upload($id,$fl,$data) {
        $this->set_id($id);
        $dir_file_num=ceil($this->id/$this->max_file_count);
        if(!is_dir($this->upload_dir.$dir_file_num)) {
            mkdir($this->upload_dir.$dir_file_num, 0777);
            chmod($this->upload_dir.$dir_file_num, 0777);
        }
        file_put_contents($this->upload_dir.$dir_file_num.'/'.$this->id.$fl, $data);
        return $this->id.$fl;
    }

    public function set_upload($id,$fl) {
        $this->set_id($id);
        $dir_file_num=ceil($this->id/$this->max_file_count);
        if(!is_dir($this->upload_dir.$dir_file_num)) {
            mkdir($this->upload_dir.$dir_file_num, 0777);
            chmod($this->upload_dir.$dir_file_num, 0777);
        }
        return $this->upload_dir.$dir_file_num.'/'.$this->id.$fl;
    }

    public function __destruct() {

    }

}
?>

$upl=new upload(array('upload_dir'=>dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/files/','max_file_count'=>15000));
$upl_filename=$upl->set_upload($id, '_'.$random_file_name);//вернет путь к картинке на сервере, само имя картинки будет вида 1_shfdhfdhfd.png где 1 это $id
move_uploaded_file($upl_filename, $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
```

Comment: а где добавление в БД?

Comment: это отдельная тема, у меня много классов и писать все было лень

логика программирования такая

- в начале в бд регистрируем новую строку (пользователя с пустыми данными) и сохраняем id в переменную

- дальше загружаем файл с помощью моего класса, он вернет имя загруженного файла

- после успешной загрузки обновляем данные в бд по id сохраненном в самом начале

найти картинку в дальнейшем очень просто, достаточно знать просто id, ведь имя картинки начинается с id_, да и папку найти очень просто

Comment: подправил немного класс, а то были ошибки

с помощью класса можно загружать не только файлы но и картинки и т.д.

в общем кому надо тот разберется

Comment: так блин

на сервере папке files нужно сделать права доступа 777 иначе туда ничего нельзя записать

в тотал командоре при доступе через ftp нужно выбрать папку и нажать Файл-изменить атрибуты...

даже можно через ssh это прописать

короче дело в правах доступа

Comment: на каком сервере, у меня локал хост

Comment: в виндоусе нет прав доступа, нужно удалить chmod и убрать второй параметр 0777 из mkdir

Comment: и вообще все сервера работают на linux так что по любому потом исправлять обратно придется

Comment: Warning: mkdir(): No such file or directory in E:\xampp\htdocs\www\s.php on line 83

эта ошибка остается, не находит путь, хотя я создал в
localhost/www/uploads/files